# Change type of pandas series/dataframe column inplace

Tags: python, pandas

**TL;DR**: I'd like to change the data types of pandas dataframe columns in-place.

---

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6.1]})
```

Which by default gets its columns assigned 'int64' and 'float64' on my system:

```
df.dtypes
Out[172]: 
a      int64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Because my dataframe will be very large, I'd like to set the column data types, after having created the dataframe, to int32 and float32. I know how I could do this:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(np.int32)
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(np.float32)
```

or, in one step:

```
df = df.astype({'a':np.int32, 'b':np.float32})
```

and the dtypes of my dataframe are indeed:

```
df.dtypes
Out[180]: 
a      int32
b    float32
dtype: object
```

**However**: this seems clunky, having to reassign the series, esp. since many pandas methods have an `inplace` kwarg. Using this, however, doesn't seem to work (starting out with the same dataframe at the top):

```
df['a'].astype(np.int32, inplace=True)

df.dtypes
Out[187]: 
a      int64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Is there something I'm overlooking here? Is this by design? The same behaviour is shown when working with `Series` instead of `DataFrame` objects.

Many thanks,

Comment: IMO inplace is clunkier than `df = df.astype({'a':np.int32, 'b':np.float32})` :)

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: `inplace` has no memory savings over re-assignment whatsoever.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not way to do it, it seems like pandas API https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html does not offer such feature.

Comment: @coldspeed, it's not about memory savings, it's about 'code flow' and how I think about the objects I'm manipulating. 'Correcting them' fits the image better than 'overwriting them with a new version of themselves'. Also, it seems an odd decision to have the `inplace` option available in some, but not in all operations. And even weirder, to have it fail silently as it does in my last example.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own (still clunky) inplace versions:

```
def astype_inplace(df: pd.DataFrame, dct: Dict):
    df[list(dct.keys())] = df.astype(dct)[list(dct.keys())]

def astype_per_column(df: pd.DataFrame, column: str, dtype):
    df[column] = df[column].astype(dtype)
```

and use it like

```
astype_inplace(df, {'bool_col':'boolean'})
```

or

```
astype_per_column(df, 'bool_col', 'boolean')
```

Comment: Hi, I get this on Google Colab
"NameError: name 'Dict' is not defined"

Do you know where this Dict function comes from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is the generic type `typing.Dict`

Comment: Still working well on 2022 just add "from typing import Dict" as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

And what about

```
>>> df.__dict__.update(df.astype({'a': np.int32, 'b': np.float32}).__dict__)
>>> df.dtypes
a      int32
b    float32
dtype: object
```

?

Answer (score -1):

pass Column names and their Datatype as a dictionary as an argument in .astype()

```
col_types = {'col_1':'type_1', 'col_4':'type_4'}
df = df.astype( col_types)
```

It will change the datatype of only that columns passed via dictionary

Comment: This isn't doing the change in place.

Answer (score -3):

@ElRudi

As I read-the-fine-manual: `copy=False` might suit your need?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.DataFrame.astype

Comment: This actually doesn't change the type of the series contained by the data frame, just manipulates it's underlying data.